# How to includes HTML on a offline single page application

Tags: html, include, offlineapps, singlepage, single-page-application

I am building a offline single page application, which use template for rendering HTML.

The application is getting bigger and since I am going to work from now with other developers, I'm wondering if something exist to include HTML.

The single page is getting too long and it would be really appreciated if we could split the 4000 lines of code of index.html which contains for the moment 8 pages, in 9 pages, with 8 includes inside the index.html.

Does anyone know a solution ?

Comment: I am curious what the app is for. Also what are using to deliver the app? Chrome embedded app?

Answer (score 1):

I use the [require.js text plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text) for this.

```
require(["text!../../Templates/template.htm"], function (template) {
    mustache.render(template, {prop: "value"});
});
```

mustache is just an example obviusly. I guess you could get the templates via $.get also but since I already use require this makes sense for me.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I will check it later.

I'm still open if there are better solution.

Btw, i am using underscore.js (required with backbone) templating engine.